# Does Child Activity can also use Parent Activity Layout Elements?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a `MainActivity`, it has a layout which has different elements; e.g: `TextBox, EditBox, Button`.

I have created a `ChildActivity` that is extending from `MainActivity`, `ChildActivity` also has a `Layout`.

My question is, can i use the layout elements of `MainActivity` and display them in my `ChildActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements you can use depend on what layout file you pass to `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout_file);` in the onCreate. So yes you can use them in both if you give both activities the same layout file, but they will be treated like separate layouts. E.g. if you set some text in a textview in Main, it will not show in Child.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can access the parent-activity element through add child-activity layout in parent-activity layout.this way you can inflate both layout in child-activity.

**ViewGroup viewGroup;** is child layout container in parent-activity.

like 
**parent activity** or **NormalActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    ViewGroup viewGroup;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState,int res) {
        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.childContainer);
        viewGroup.addView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(res, viewGroup,false));
    }
}
```

**Child Activity**

```
public class ChildActivity extends MainActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState,R.layout.child_layout);

    }

}
```